# textarea border not working in css

Tags: css

I am trying to put in css textarea border attributes.  But I don't seem to be getting it to work - no border displays.  This is in Angular2 if it makes a difference.  Once I get it working I want to move the cols and rows attributes to the CSS, also.  I know I have 2 borders - this was to, hopefully, see one of them.  I really only want the outline.

```css
    payload-entry {
      border: 1px solid black;
      outline: 5px dotted red;
    }
```

```html
<textarea mdInput ng-attr-placeholder="Payload" rows="4" cols="50" class="payload-entry"  [formControl]="apiTestForm.controls['payload']"></textarea>
```

Comment: is it a typo or are you just missing the `.` before `payload-entry` in your css?

Comment: add a `.` before `payload-entry` in your css

Comment: Voted to close as typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To assign CSS to a class, you must prefix the class with a period. In this case, instead of

```
   payload-entry {
      border: 1px solid black;
      outline: 5px dotted red;
    }
```

use

```
   .payload-entry {
      border: 1px solid black;
      outline: 5px dotted red;
    }
```

If you had `id="this-textarea"`, you would use a pound sign instead.

```
   #this-textarea {
      border: 1px solid black;
      outline: 5px dotted red;
    }
```

Comment: this change worked.  However, now the left side of the outline is not showing.  If I click into the text area the entire border appears properly

Comment: This is what I am getting